# Backbone Bootstrap modal handle close

Tags: backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, backbone-views, bootstrap-modal

I have bootstrap modal. Close and save I can handle with events:

```
    events: {
        'click #back': 'close',
        'click #save': 'save',
        'keydown': 'keyHandler'
    },
```

But is one problem, I cant handle when user click on `.fade` and close modal. How to handle this click - modal  close ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you are trying to accomplish because we don't see all of the code.

It's a bad idea to simply only check for a .fade click.  It's too generic and you could have another .fade somewhere else in the view.  One thing could do is:

```
 events: {
    'click #back': 'close',
    'click .fade.modal': 'close',
    'click #save': 'save',
    'keydown': 'keyHandler'
},
```

This works, but this is a bad idea because if the user clicks anywhere on the modal it closes it.

You could also listen for the close event on the modal.

```js
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
        'click #back': 'close',
        'click #save': 'save',
        'keydown': 'keyHandler'
   },
  initialize: function() {

  },
  render: function() {
    $('#myModal').modal()
    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', this.closeModal)
  },
  closeModal: function(){
    $('#myModal').off('hidden.bs.modal')  //prevent memory leak
    this.close()
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is remove the 
"data-dismiss="modal"" from your HTML

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>`

and separately handle the click event and close the Modal using `$('#your_modal_id').modal('hide');`

This way you can handle the Modal close thing.